# Is there a way in sqlplus to display a conditional column heading?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Would like to be able to display a conditional column heading, based on the select results, in sql*plus.  So in example below, would like to display `A_DATE` header if value is `A`, or the `begin/end_date column` heading otherwise:

```
SELECT
CASE thingy
    WHEN 'A' THEN TO_CHAR(a_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') "A_DATE"
    ELSE TO_CHAR(begin_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')  || ' '  
        || TO_CHAR(end_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')  "BEGIN_DATE  END_DATE"
END,
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  If the query returned more than one row you run the risk of ambiguity.  You could return two columns though.  Something like this:

```
select case when my condition is met then myfield else null end "true column"
, case when my my condition is not met then myfield else null end "false column"
```

Comment: Oh, now that sounds interesting.  I'll give this a try!  Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Well, it's close, however this prints both columns, but 1 of the 2 will just have null values underneath it.